# jquery load function get only div instead of whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I apologize if you've already seen this. I'm still struggling a bit with this. I just need to modify the function to load only the colTwo div from the link selected on the menu instead of the entire page.

I see the code from the jquery website:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

But I don't understand how to make the function do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Title</title>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src ='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function(){
        $('#menu li a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var page_url=$(this).prop('href');
            $('#colTwo').load(page_url);
        });
    });


</script>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">

    <div id="colOne">

        <div id="menu1">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="members.html">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-news">
            <h2>Recent Updates</h2>
            <p><strong>None At This Time</strong> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="colTwo"><h2>Starting Text</h2></div>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... string concatenation maybe?

Comment: I'm confused. You're trying to load content via AJAX from the page you're on into the page you're on? Your example doesn't make sense.

Comment: @j08691 I think you misread; that code grabs the `href` from the clicked anchor in the menu `ul` and fetches it.

Comment: @Mathletics - I'm definitely confused. The line "load only the colTwo div from the link selected" is getting me. Maybe if we knew where the loaded content was going it would clear it up.

Comment: @j08691 ah yes, ok, I see what you mean now. I'm _assuming_ that OP has a standard template where `colOne` is the menu and `colTwo` is the content. So he wants to pull the content from, say, the `members` page into the current page async. Then again, if Kevin's and my answer is correct, it would suggest AJAX navigation may be a bit "out of his league" ;-)

Comment: yes its a standard template, they all have colTwo, and yes ajax navigation is way out of my league, I don't know the basics of javascript syntax yet including concatenation. Thanks for getting me started though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kevin B is correct:

```
$('#colTwo').load(page_url + ' #colTwo');
```

Just add the selector as a string to the URL, and don't forget the space!